# Setting up EntityFramework SQL Server on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, windows-server-2012-r2

This is the first time I've ever had to use a Windows server for publishing so forgive my ignorance.

I have a dedicated server with Windows Server 2012 r2 installed. I have setup the FTP publishing in order to publish the site via Visual Studio. The site works fine unless I try and use a feature that requires a database connection.
The project I am developing uses EntityFramework to handle the SQL database.

And I receive the following error:

> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]

Connection strings
[image: https://gyazo.com/b29d87b5478c3bd6d6627f94dd853b32.png]

**CentralDb**

`metadata=res://*/CentralDb.csdl|res://*/CentralDb.ssdl|res://*/CentralDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\centraldb.mdf;integrated`

**DefaultConnection**

`Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-BetCentral-20161230033657.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-BetCentral-20161230033657;Integrated Security=True`

**LocalSqlServer**

`data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true`

I've done a bit of Googling for this error and I have found multiple answers that are very varied and have not helped me correct my problem.

Comment: are you using the right connection string? You can use a .udl file to test your connection string.

Comment: @M56 [Photo of connection strings](https://gyazo.com/b29d87b5478c3bd6d6627f94dd853b32.png)  The database is called `centraldb.mdf` and is stored in App_Data. I've never had to deal with connection strings before.

Comment: Please paste your connection strings into the question **as text**

Comment: have you installed sql server?

Comment: @M56 Yes I've installed SQL Server 2012.

Comment: in cmd windows put "SQLCMD -L" to list all instance installed and check if is "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB"

Comment: What i gather from that information is that you do not have the local db feature enabled. Try and change the connection strings that mention the localdb to your .\sqlexpress instance.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but you would be surprised at how often this is the answer to similar customer questions.  Is the SQL Server service running?